# Finding components of constraint in Catia via macro

Tags: macros, constraints, catia

does anyone know hot to get information via Catia macros about component (planes, faces, axis etc.) used in making constraint?

Answer (score 0):

the CHM file shows:

```
Func GetConstraintElement( long  iElementNumber) As CATIAReference
```

Reads an element of a constraint. 
Parameters:

```
iElementNumber
```

The number of the element of the constraint to be read. (1 for the first element,2 for the second, 3 for the third). Notice it must not exceed the total number of elements of the constraint. (eg : not allowed to read the third element of a tangency).

```
oCurrentElement
```

An element of the constraint.

Example: 
The following example reads the first element of a constraint 
 Dim reference1 As Reference
 reference1=tangencyCst.GetConstraintElement( 1 )

AND

```
Sub SetConstraintElement( long  iElementNumber, CATIAReference  iNewElement)
```

Replaces an element of a constraint. 
Parameters:

```
iElementNumber
```

The number of the element of the constraint to replace. (1 for the first element,2 for the second, 3 for the third).

```
iNewElement
```

A new element of the constraint.

Example: 
The following example changes the second element of a constraint

```
Dim reference1 As Reference
tangencyCst.SetConstraintElement ( 2, reference1)
```